# Unity 2017.3 Editor Crash when use EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

When I use EditorUtiliy.OpenFolderPanel method for getting directory path on operating system(macOSX in Unity 2017.3, the editor is crashed always. When I use the same method in Unity 2017.2 or older versions of Unity, the editor is not crashed.

How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Thanks for your time.

```
 private void SetRootDirectory()
{
    string path = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/root.txt";
    string rootPath = EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel("Select Location", Application.dataPath, ""); //editor is crashing because of this line

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            writer.Write(rootPath);
        }

    }

    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Probably ought to ask in the Unity Forums as this is Editor specific

Comment: Thanks for your advice @SurajS, I just ask the question in UnityForums too. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1446417/unity-20173-editor-crash-when-use-editorutilityope.html

Comment: There are a lot of bugs in 2017.3. A LOT. So suggest you to roll back or wait for any patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Detailed Answer](https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?981789_k3pvjgh9nob0fce6)

Thanks for the solution to Unity Team. They solved the problem in Unity 2018.1.

Email details:

> Hey,
>
> Thanks a lot for reporting an issue.
>
> It appears that this bug has already been fixed in 2018.1. It is
>   uncertain when this issue will be fixed for 2017.3, so I would suggest
>   downgrading to the latest 2017.2 patch release.
>
> You can download latest patch releases of Unity from here:
>   https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases
>
> If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.
>
> Regards, Linas QA team